# When I add comments to my blog, the comments show on every blog rather than the one it was posted on

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I’m trying to add comments to a blog post, and have them show up on the same page as the blog. The comments that are posted on that blog then show up on every blog
This is my code in the blog controller

```
 def index
    @blogs = Blog.all

  end

  def show
    @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
    @blogs = Blog.all
    @comment = @blog.comments.build
  end

  def new
    @blog = Blog.new
  end

  def create
    @blog = Blog.new(blog_params)
    @blog.user = current_user
    if @blog.save
      redirect_to blogs_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Comments controller

```
  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def create
    @blog = Blog.find(params[:blog_id])
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    @comment.blog = @blog
    @comment.user = current_user
    @comment.save
    redirect_to blog_path(@blog)
  end

  def show
    @comments = Comment.new
  end
```

views/blogs/show.html.erb

```
    <% @blogs.each do |blog| %>
      <div class="comment-box">
        <% blog.comments.each do |c| %>
          <p><%= c.body %></p>
```

Comment: Please add expected output and actual output in question.

Answer (score 1):

your show method in blog controller should be as below:

```
def show
  @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
  @blogs = Blog.all
  @comments = @blog.comments
end
```

Also, you can refactor the `comments_controller.rb` as below:

```
def create
  @blog = Blog.find(params[:blog_id])
  @comments = @blog.comments.build(comment_params.merge({user: current_user}))
  @comments.save
  redirect_to blog_path(@blog)
end
```

Hope this will help you.